# sqlite database in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I retain all the row from login table? I can retain only one row, why not others? Am I using wrong query? Please check my code:

```
#import "loginAppDelegate.h"
#import "global.h"
#import <sqlite3.h>
#import "logincontroller.h"

@implementation loginAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize loginView;
//databaseName=@"login.sqlite";

-(void) chekAndCreateDatabase
{
    BOOL success;
    //sqlite3   *databaseName=@"login.sqlite";
    NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *documentPaths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir =[documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString    *databasePath=[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"login.sqlite"];
    success=[fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
    if(success)return;

    NSString *databasePathFromApp=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"login.sqlite"];

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
    [fileManager release];
}


-(void) Data
{

    Gpass=@"";
    Guname=@"";
sqlite3_stmt *detailStmt=nil;
//sqlite3   *databaseName;

    NSArray *documentPaths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir =[documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *databasePath=[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"login.sqlite"];
    [self chekAndCreateDatabase];

    sqlite3 *database;
    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String],&database)==SQLITE_OK) {
        if (detailStmt==nil) {
            const char *sql= "select *from Loginchk where uname='%?'and password='%?'";
            //NSString *sql = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Loginchk WHERE uname ='%@' and password ='%@' ",Uname.text,Password.text];
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,sql,-1,&detailStmt,NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {

                sqlite3_bind_text(detailStmt,1,[Gunameq UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(detailStmt,2,[Gpassq UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                if (SQLITE_DONE!= sqlite3_step(detailStmt)) {
                    Guname=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(detailStmt,0)];
                    Gpass =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(detailStmt,1)];
                    NSLog(@"'%@'",Guname);
                    NSLog(@"'%@'",Gpass);

                }
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(detailStmt);
        }
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
    }
```

Comment: @user692277: Please edit your question, it is very hard to understand what you mean. Please use punctuation (`.`, `,`, ...) and be much more clear about what your code is doing and what you want it to do.

Comment: You mean get all rows instead of one row from Loginchk table?

Comment: i need all rows from loginchk table and also validation from text which enter by user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Declare Class as Following to store user details UserDetails.h

@interface UserDetails : NSObject 
{
    NSString *strUserName;
    NSString *strPassword;
}
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSString * strUserName;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString * strPassword;

//Declare Class as Following to store user details UserDetails.m
@implementation UserDetails 
@synthesize strUserName,strPassword;
-(void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    [strUserName release];
    [strPassword release];
}

//Declare Class as Following to store user details Your ApplicationDelegate.m file
-(NSMutableArray)getAllUserDetails
{
    sqlite3_stmt *selectStmt = nil; 
    NSArray *documentPaths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir =[documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath=[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"login.sqlite"];
    [self chekAndCreateDatabase];

    NSMutableArray *arrUsers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    const char *sqlStatement = "your query";

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &selectStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
{
    // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
    while(sqlite3_step(selectStmt) == SQLITE_ROW) 
    {
        UserDetails *objUserDetail = [[UserDetails alloc] init];
        objUserDetail.userName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectStmt, 1)];
        objUserDetail.password = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectStmt, 2)];
        [arrUsers addObject:objUserDetail];
        [objUserDetail release];
    }
}
// Release the compiled statement from memory
sqlite3_finalize(selectStmt);
selectStmt = nil;
```

}

call this function in button click event as

```
-(IBAction)btnLogin
{
    BOOL isUserExists = NO;
    NSMutableArray *arrAllUsers = [loginAppDelegate getAllUserDetails];
    //Normal Checking Stuff
    for(UserDetails *objUser in arrAllUsers)
    {
        if([txtUserTextBox.text isEqualToString:objUser.strUserName] && [txtPasswordTextBox.text isEqualToString:objUser.strPassword])
        {
            //True Login
            isUserExists = YES;
            break;
        }
    }

    //Check your stuff if user exists or not what to do
    if(isUserExists)
    {
        Heading to next screen;
    }
    else
    {
        Alertmessage
    }
}
```

Comment: hi friend can u help me in this

Comment: hi frien i try but i have one question that i have to delet mu appdeleget code and create one other class if it is then it not working

Comment: I have again edited with more comments and that should work with your application. Please bear with me if any typos are there. Hope this time you get it working.

Comment: sorry friend this time my code not bind the data it's not working sorry